# `[ERROR] 'mirrors.mirror.mirrorOf' for central is missing`

Tags: pom.xml, maven-3, nexus, nexus3, maven-repository

## What are the details of your problem?

How do you resolve a broken apart [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/) and [Shibboleth](https://build.shibboleth.net/maven/releases) repositories?
I'm unable to easily set Maven mirrors because hosted mirrors are hodgepodge of different groups.
We're not in a position to ask again and they have not resolved them into a unified mirror repository.

```
ERROR Error executing Maven.
ERROR 8 problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[ERROR] 'mirrors.mirror.mirrorOf' for central is missing @ C:\Users\user\.m2\settings.xml
[ERROR] 'mirrors.mirror.mirrorOf' for central is missing @ C:\Users\user\.m2\settings.xml
[ERROR] 'mirrors.mirror.mirrorOf' for central is missing @ C:\Users\user\.m2\settings.xml
[ERROR] 'mirrors.mirror.mirrorOf' for central is missing @ C:\Users\user\.m2\settings.xml
[ERROR] 'mirrors.mirror.mirrorOf' for central is missing @ C:\Users\user\.m2\settings.xml
[ERROR] 'mirrors.mirror.mirrorOf' for central is missing @ C:\Users\user\.m2\settings.xml
[ERROR] 'mirrors.mirror.mirrorOf' for central is missing @ C:\Users\user\.m2\settings.xml
[ERROR] 'mirrors.mirror.mirrorOf' for central is missing @ C:\Users\user\.m2\settings.xml
```

## What did you try and what were you expecting?

I tried providing just the repositories so Maven would check the repositories to find which to resolve to.
I gave the `<mirrorOf>central</mirror>` to tell Maven when central was split into multiple repositories so Maven could know which fractured repositories to parse through.
I've tried to use the main [Sonatype Nexus Repository](https://www.sonatype.com/products/sonatype-nexus-repository) URL so that it'd self resolve. None of these worked, btw.

```
Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact group.id:artifact.id:version.id from/to nexus (nexus.website): company.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Sounds like you are working with an untrusted certificate. You have to import this to you keystore which is used by maven

Comment: @Jens I am but that's not the main issue right now. I can't just switch the repository setup because of the certification though.

Comment: You shouldn't change the repo, the cange can be done client side

Comment: This: `https://mvnrepository.com/` is not central repository...This is the search engine for central repository: https://central.sonatype.com/ and that is the real content: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/